# Angular. Фабрика сервисов

Tags: javascript, typescript, angular

У меня есть три сервиса. Два сервиса выполняют определённый похожий функционал и у обоих есть некое поле value, а третий сервис в зависимости от поступающего значения должен выбирать определённый сервис из двух.

```
@Injectable({providedIn: "root"})
export class ServiceController {
  service: FirstService | SecondService;
  isNeedSecondService: boolean = true;
  constructor(private firstService: FirstService , private secondService: SecondService) {
    if (this.needSecondService) {
      this.service = this.secondService;
    } else {
      this.service = this.firstService;
    }
  }
}
```

Вопрос состоит в том как мне изменить ServiceController и заинжектить нужный сервис в компоненте, чтобы я мог обращаться к value, как this.service.value?

```
@Component({
  selector: "app-root",
  templateUrl: "./app.component.html",
  styleUrls: ["./app.component.css"],
  changeDetection: ChangeDetectionStrategy.OnPush
})
export class AppComponent {
  constructor (private service: ServiceController) {
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Заведите базовый абстрактный класс для сервисов. Допустим

```
abstract class BaseService {
    public value: any;
}
```

И наследуйте от него ваши сервисы:

```
class FirstService extends BaseService {}
...
class SecondService extends BaseService {}
```

Далее немного измените ServiceController:

```
class ServiceController {
    private service?: BaseService;

    constructor(private first: FirstService, private second: SevondService) {
        this.setFirstService(true);
    }

    // текущий сервис меняется в зависимости от параметра value
    public setFirstService(value: boolean): void {
        this.service = value ? this.first : this.second;
    }
}
```

Этот архитектурный  шаблон называется `Стратегия`